# Vlc-qt subtitles

Tags: c++, libvlc, vlc-qt

How to switch on/off subtitles in vlc-qt media player? By default subtitles switched on.

I use this stuff:

```
#include <VLCQtCore/Common.h>
#include <VLCQtCore/Instance.h>
#include <VLCQtCore/Media.h>
#include <VLCQtCore/MediaPlayer.h>
#include <VLCQtCore/Audio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your vlcMediaPlayer (i'll call it media since you didn't show any code) object try

```
media.video()->setSubtitle(-1);
```

VlcMediaPlayer has a video object which is the one calling the video functions in which the setSubtitle one resides. See this [vlc-qt/Video.h](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/blob/cadc9e2c7b1b1b25f892eed1d15691b89fe5bef3/src/core/Video.h)